# Query refuses to use index

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-slow-query-log

Using MySQL version 5.5.28,

I have a table defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `desc` text NOT NULL,
  `permissions` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple.  I have a primary key on the id field.  Now, I query against it using something like this:

```
SELECT permissions FROM groups WHERE id IN ('9', '8', '6','14','11','7','5');
```

Unfortunately it refuses to use the key, and it shows up in my slow query log.

Performing EXPLAIN on it provides:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT permissions FROM groups WHERE id IN ('9', '8', '6','14','11','7','5');
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | groups | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   16 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It only has less than 20 rows in the entire table, so I get why it wouldn't likely use the index.  But, why would this be a "slow query" for MySQL?

Comment: Could it be that mysql is confused because you are passing the IN values as strings? Try IN ( 9, 8, 6, ... ) ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in )

Comment: Try passing actual integer values in your WHERE clause instead of strings.

Comment: Nope, passing integers has no bearing on the index use - with small tables I get that.  I think a1ex07 below may have what I'm looking for.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a small number of rows, full scan will almost always be the fastest way to access the table. Also, selectivity important - even if id is unique, the query returns around 30% of all rows (assuming you have 20). It appears in slow query log not because it's slow, but because it doesn't use index (it should be an option to control that behaviour, I just don't remember it from the top of my head)

**Update** I just double checked, option is [log-queries-not-using-indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes)

Comment: That looks like what I needed - I knew that MySQL wouldn't use indexes on tiny tables, but the fact that it was being logged as "slow" was confusing me.  Now I see why.  Changing that option took them out of the log so I can focus on the real issues.